# How can I pass through

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, getjson

```
var url1="https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/";
var channelList= ["channel1","channel2",channel3"];



//I am trying to create for loop to define url with different channel names.

for(var i=0;i<channelList.length;i++){
  var url="https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels/" + channelList[i];
  $.getJSON(url1+channelList[i],function(data){

    //When the user click off button,I want to show offline channels.
    $("#off").on("click", () => {
      if(data.stream === null) {
        $.getJSON(url,function(seconddata){

          $("#main").append("<div class='row' style='margin-top:5px;'><div class='col-md-4'><p><img src='"+seconddata.logo+"'width='42' height='42'>"+"      "+"<a href='"+seconddata.url+"' target=_blank>"+seconddata.display_name+"</a></p></div></div>")   
      });
    }
  });      
});
```

Hello , I am really new to coding. Nowadays I follow the FreeCodeCamp and I am struggling with the Twitch viewer project. But I am stuck on the code :) 
 I want to create a for loop and use an api to get all channel's data. But I get only last channel's data because "i" is increased outside of the jquery functions. It is not going through the jquery functions. How can I fix it? :)

Thank you in advance for your replies.

Note: Sorry for my english. It is not my mother tongue. :) I hope you can understand my problem.

Comment: This is probably just a copy/paste error but, you're missing a quotation mark in your channelList array at the beginning of `channel3`

Comment: Yes, I forgot it when I change channel names. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the logic like the following code snippet.

```
var url1="https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/";
var channelList= ["channel1","channel2","channel3"];

var allData = [];

//I am trying to create for loop to define url with different channel names.

for(var i=0;i<channelList.length;i++) {
  var url="https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels/" + channelList[i];
  $.getJSON(url1+channelList[i],function(data){
    allData.push(data);
  });
};

   //When the user click off button,I want to show offline channels.
    $("#off").on("click", () => {
      for (var j=0;j<channelList.length; j++) {
        var data = allData[j];
        if(data.stream === null) {
        $.getJSON(url,function(seconddata){

          $("#main").append("<div class='row' style='margin-top:5px;'><div class='col-md-4'><p><img src='"+seconddata.logo+"'width='42' height='42'>"+"      "+"<a href='"+seconddata.url+"' target=_blank>"+seconddata.display_name+"</a></p></div></div>") 


        });
       }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Let me know in case you get any errors. I have only dry run it. It may have some syntax issues. So let me know if it gives some error in your working code.

Comment: Hey, I got still only last channel's data. But I have just changed url position and put it in  last if structure. Then it's working now:)) I am really appreciate :) Thank you so much :)